# Sql - Have a big query which need to be filter out duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a massive query which joins about 70 tables and returns over 200 columns:

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID, TABLEB.ID, TABLEC.ID  ...
FROM TABLEA LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLE.FID LEFT JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEB.ID = TABLEC.FID ...
WHERE [some conditions]
```

This result has one unique primary column it should return which is TABLEA.ID. All the values in the column should be unique, but due to bad data collection there are some duplicates. So I have some ID which are duplicates and they have other columns with different values. From these duplicates I know which specific rows I need to grab and which duplicates I can discard (ex. grab the row where TABLEA.ID = 9999 and TABLEZ.SOMECOLUMN = 'JOHN DOE').

So the final resultset looks something like this:

```
TABLEA.ID | TABLEB.ID | TABLEZ.SOMECOLUMN .....
     1         fjash       BOB
     2         dfd         BOB
     3         34g         JOHN
     3         vfg         KIM
     3         vsd         OBI-WAN
     4         vgsdfg      NICK
     4         fg          HA
     5         hggh        HAHA
```

From this I know which duplicated I need to filter out to get something like this:

```
TABLEA.ID | TABLEB.ID | TABLEZ.SOMECOLUMN .....
     1         fjash       BOB
     2         dfd         BOB
     3         34g         JOHN
     4         vgsdfg      NICK
     5         hggh        HAHA
```

I thought this would be easy as I would simple filter them out in the where clause but it has turned out to be more complicated than I thought.

```
 SELECT TABLEA.ID, TABLEB.ID, TABLEC.ID  ...
    FROM TABLEA LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLE.FID LEFT JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEB.ID = TABLEC.FID ...
    WHERE [some conditions]
    AND (TABLEA.ID = 9999 AND TABLEZ.SOMECOLUMN = 'JOHN DOE')
```

But this only returns one row instead. I tried another combination by trying to negate it:

```
AND (TABLEA.ID = 9999 AND TABLEZ.SOMECOLUMN <> 'OTHER VALUE OTHER THAN JOE DOE')
```

But this also does not work.

Comment: It seems that you have groups of row per `tablea.id`. the question is: which row from the group you need?

Comment: @RadimBača Yes this is the issue. Due to bad data entry there are duplicate tablea.id. I have a list given which rows are invalid so I need to remove them "manually". So the answer to do that is I know from a list of invalid records. My question then is how to best filter out these invalid rows.

Comment: I'm asking this: can you write the RULE how you recognize invalid rows in group?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am trying to help with the pseudo code in the same language. Please try to relate.

Try using row_number over partition by id (to be unique) and filter row_number 1 values:
Try avoiding preferred value for ID because you want this column as unique in your output dataset.

Try:

```
SELECT TABLEA.ID, TABLEB.ID, TABLEC.ID  ...
FROM
    (SELECT TABLEA.ID, TABLEB.ID, TABLEC.ID  ...
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TABLEA.ID 
                     ORDER BY CASE WHEN TABLEX.SOMECOLUMN = 'Some preferred value' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                              CASE WHEN TABLEZ.SOMEOTHERCOL='Some other preferred value' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
                              ROWNUM) RN
        FROM TABLEA LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEA.ID = TABLE.FID LEFT JOIN TABLEC  
        ON TABLEB.ID = TABLEC.FID ...
        WHERE [some conditions])
WHERE RN=1;
```